# Скачивание файла по ссылке с использованием логина, пароля используя NTLM или Kerberos

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, аутентификация, ntlm

Пытаюсь при помощи питона скачать файл по url. Доступ к сайту, на котором расположен файл требует логин и пароль. Поэтому

```
import urllib.request

url = "someurl.asp?WCI=GetText&url=somefile.rar"
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

возвращает **#HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**

**Update:** 
Попробовал с requests:

```
response = requests.get('url',auth=('login','pass'))
print (response.content)
```

ответ - "You are not authorized to view this page"

WWW-Authenticate заголовок из ответа: 'Negotiate, NTLM'

**Update 2:**
Попробовал с помощью библиотеки requests-ntml

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

url = "http://.../normdocs/default.asp"
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('http://.../normdocs\\login','password', session)
session.get('http://.../normdocs/')
```

Результат все тот же **401**

Comment: Рекомендуемый метод это [использовать requests, но если необходимо, то можно и urllib использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509568/4279)

Comment: Попробовал с requests: `response = requests.get('url',auth=('login','pass'))`  `print (response.content)`  ответ - "You are not authorized to view this page"

Comment: 'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Negotiate, NTLM'

Comment: попробуйте, [по ссылками из документации пакеты](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#other-authentication), например: `from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth; requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Authentication issues with WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4265975/4279)

Comment: подозреваю, что слово domain означает example.com а не `http://example.com` (url). Попробуйте посмотреть, какие заголовки браузер посылает, в котором у вас получается залогиниться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сервере настроена аутентификация с использование Kerberos. И вам сперва нужно получить билет для сервера, чтобы запросить данный ресурс.

Согласно [RFC 4559](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559)

Клиент запрашивает защищенный от доступа документ с сервера через
GET. URI документа является "http://www.nowhere.org/dir/index.html".

```
Client: GET dir/index.html
```

В первый раз, когда клиент запрашивает документ - клиент не отправляет заголовок с авторизацией, поэтому сервер отвечает:

```
Server: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

Клиент получает учетные данные пользователя с помощью SPNEGO GSSAPI.
И отправляет на сервер с новым запросом, включая заголовок для авторизации:

```
Client: GET dir/index.html
Client: <headers> Authorization: Negotiate a87421000492aa874209af8bc028
```

Сервер декодирует gssapi-данные и передает их в SPNEGO
Механизм gssapi в функции gss_accept_security_context.

```
Server: HTTP/1.1 200 Success
Server: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate ade0234568a4209af8bc0280289eca
```

Для удобной работы со SPNEGO GSSAPI используете библиотеку [python-gssapi](https://pythongssapi.github.io/python-gssapi/stable/index.html)